# Display plot information only when cursor is on it - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a plot like this
[image]

There are 30 lines on this plot and each line corresponds to a particular object. Now I want to display all the object's name. But I don't want a messy legend with 30 entries.

What I want is to be able to hover the cursor over any line (or use the data cursor) and then it object's name should appear.

Is that possible to do in Matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing text that appears when *hovering* over an object is doable, but can be quite involved. It would require setting a [`WindowButtonMotionFcn` callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) for your figure which would continuously check the [`CurrentPoint` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) of the figure to determine if it was within your axes of interest, and if so then check the [`CurrentPoint` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) of that axes and compute which child plot object is the closest.

If you're willing to allow the user to *click* and not just *hover* for text to appear, that's much simpler. You could set the [`ButtonDownFcn` callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html) of each plotted line to display text in a given location. Here's an example that creates two line objects and assigns them a callback function that will display the `Tag` of the line that is clicked on at the cursor point:

```
function line_click_example

  hAxes = axes('NextPlot', 'add', 'ButtonDownFcn', @clear_text);
  hLines = line(hAxes, [1:10; 1:10].', [rand(10, 1) rand(10, 1)+1]);
  set(hLines, 'ButtonDownFcn', @line_click_fcn, ...
              'Tag', {'Line 1'; 'Line 2'});
  hText = text(hAxes, 0, 0, '');

  function line_click_fcn(hSource, ~)
    cursorPosition = get(get(hSource, 'Parent'), 'CurrentPoint');
    set(hText, 'Position', cursorPosition(1, [1 2]), ...
               'String', get(hSource, 'Tag'));
  end

  function clear_text(~, ~)
    set(hText, 'Position', [0 0], 'String', '');
  end

end
```

Here, I've also set the `ButtonDownFcn` of the axes so that it will clear the text object, meaning that clicking on any region of the axes that isn't over one of the two lines will remove the displayed text. Notice also that, since `line_click_fcn` and `clear_text` are [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), they will both have access to `hText` and be able to modify it.